# Update gradle version for google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run my java application on Google Cloud App Engine, I'm getting following error: 
`org.gradle.api.GradleException: Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 2.12`

I tried to update the `gradle-wrapper.properties` to use gradle 4.5.1 and uploaded my own `gradle-wrapper.jar`

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Tue Apr 17 09:15:25 SGT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-all.zip
```

I try to run the `gradle init --type java-library` to update the version and also tried `gradle appengineBuild` and `gradle appengineDeploy` but all of them give the same error message with the `--stacktrace` tag.

I also tried to restart the project but when i run the `gradle init --type java-library` command to startup a new project, it installs the *2.12 version*

Does anyone have any idea what to do to fix this ?

---

*full error message:*

```
marketing@online-marketing-buddy:~$ gradle appengineStage --stacktrace
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/marketing/build.gradle' line: 34
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'onlinemarketingbuddydb'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 2.12
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'onlinemarketingbuddydb'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:155)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:160)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:532)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:153)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:35)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_54mc3xq3ckzqrdj7771r1b8xz.run(/home/marketing/build.gradle:34)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 2.12
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.verifyGradleVersion(SpringBootPlugin.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.apply(SpringBootPlugin.java:77)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.apply(SpringBootPlugin.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:137)
        ... 58 more
```

---

***Edit***

I used following tutorials: [Using Gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor) and [Gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle)

With both tutorials i get the same end result, which is the error.
I tried using following command to change the gradle version:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.7 init --type java-application
```

Here the Error is : `Execution failed for task ':init'. > The requested build setup type 'java-application' is not supported.`. When the project is already set up it gives the original error when running this command.

So i tried using `--type basic` but this also gives me the original error.

When trying `gradlew` following error comes up:

```
    marketing@online-marketing-buddy:~/OnlineMarketingBuddyDB_AppEngine$ ./gradlew.bat 
-bash: ./gradlew.bat: Permission denied
```

I have no clue what to do next.

Comment: I also tried the `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.7 init --type java-library` command but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you try with gradlew instead of gradle?

Comment: Yes, with `gradlew` i get folloing issue:

`marketing@online-marketing-buddy:~/OnlineMarketingBuddyDB_AppEngine$ ./gradlew.bat`
`-bash: ./gradlew.bat: Permission denied`

Comment: Wow there is so much going on here -- first off, you might wish to try java-application instead of java-library.  Then validate the current version of the libraries.  I see your using App Engine.  Have you looked at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-gradle ??

Comment: I'll try following command `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.7 init --type java-application` and will come back to you, I haven't tried that specific page, but almost exactly the same: [cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle)

Comment: `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.7 init --type java-application
:wrapper
:init FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init'.
> The requested build setup type 'java-application' is not supported. Supported types: 'basic', 'groovy-library', 'java-library', 'pom', 'scala-library'.
BUILD FAILED`
 after using the above command

Comment: I have noticed that you have posted one App Engine flexible environment link and one App Engine standard link. Which one fits your Java application better (check [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/))? I would like to clarify this so we can focus on one environment.

Comment: it's the standard environment that i am using. still stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I have followed the next steps to fix it:

1. Follow [Gradle in AE standard environment guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle) until "Testing your application with the development server" step 3 (excluded).
2. In Google Cloud Shell, go to `/opt/` folder and execute `rm -rf gradle` to uninstall Gradle version 2.12. Remove `gradle`, `gradle.w` and `.gradle` in your application folder. You might have something different here.
3. Download the compatible version you want from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/).
4. Unzip the new Gradle version in two places: `/opt/` and your application folder. You will need `sudo` permissions in `/opt/` folder to perform any operation. E.g.: `sudo unzip gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip`
5. Change the Gradle installation folder name in both places to `gradle`. E.g.: `sudo mv gradle-4.5.1 gradle`.
6. Run `gradle appengineRun` in your application folder.